# Access Current logged in Users download folder in c# windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, winapi, windows-services

i have windows service which is deployed using service.msc using c#,

i want to access the current logged in users download folder

eg: if the current logged in username is admin, then i want to access

C:\Users\admin\Downloads

and if the current logged in username is tomas, then i want to acess

C:\Users\tomas\Downloads.

Comment: What if there are multiple users logged in at the same time?

Comment: What if there aren't *any* users logged in?

Comment: there is only one single user and its not in any domain, its a standalone pc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Downloads)`, passing in a token for the desired user account. The trick will be in knowing which user you want. There may be more than one user logged in at the same time. There may be no users logged in at all. If your service is running under the SYSTEM account, it can enumerate active user sessions via `WTSEnumerateSessions()` and get their user token via `WTSQueryUserToken()`.